# Can not get sample Terraform Azure App Service code to deploy

Tags: terraform, azure-web-app-service, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to deploy the sample App Service using Terraform from these instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/provision-resource-terraform

I keep getting a "GatewayTimeout" error when the code tries to deploy the sourcecontrol.

[image]

Anyone know why this is not working?

Tried a different GitHub repo but still same result. Tried to use version 3.57 of the hashicorp/azurerm but does not work. Triedd to change branch to 'main' instead of master. Expecting the sample code to work and function

Answer (score 1):

Check the following:

```
resource "azurerm_service_plan" "appserviceplan" {
  name                = "webapp-asp-random"
  location              = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name   = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "B1"
}

# Create the web app, pass in the App Service Plan ID
resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "webapp" {
  name                  = "webapp-rand"
  location              = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name   = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  service_plan_id       = azurerm_service_plan.appserviceplan.id
  https_only            = true
  site_config { 
    minimum_tls_version = "1.2"
  }
}



Deploy code from a public GitHub reporesource
 "azurerm_app_service_source_control" "sourcecontrol" {
   app_id             = azurerm_linux_web_app.webapp.id
   repo_url           = "https://github.com/Azure-Samples/nodejs-docs-hello-world"
   branch             = "master"
   use_manual_integration = true
   use_mercurial      = false
 }
```

same error oocured with that github code.

```
Error: creating Source Control configuration for Web App: (Site Name "webapp-rand" / Resource Group "xx"): web.AppsClient#UpdateSourceControl: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=504 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=504 Code="GatewayTimeout" Message="The gateway did not receive a response from 'Microsoft.Web' within the specified time period."
│
│   with azurerm_app_service_source_control.sourcecontrol,
│   on main.tf line 86, in resource "azurerm_app_service_source_control" "sourcecontrol":
│   86: resource "azurerm_app_service_source_control" "sourcecontrol
```

[image]

Following code to deploy app service worked:
Source code from [azurerm_app_service_source_control | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform Registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/app_service_source_control)

**main.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_service_plan" "appserviceplan" {
  name                = "webapp-random"
  location              = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name   = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "B1"
}

# Create the web app, pass in the App Service Plan ID
resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "webapp" {
  name                  = "webapp-rand"
  location              = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name   = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  service_plan_id       = azurerm_service_plan.appserviceplan.id
  https_only            = true
  site_config { 
    minimum_tls_version = "1.2"
  }
}



resource "azurerm_app_service_source_control" "example" {
  app_id   = azurerm_linux_web_app.webapp.id
  repo_url = "https://github.com/Azure-Samples/python-docs-hello-world"
  branch   = "master"
 use_manual_integration = true
 use_mercurial      = false
}
```

I have following providers :

**providers.tf:**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      //version = "=3.0.2"
      version = "=3.50.0"
    }

    azapi = {
      source  = "azure/azapi"
      version = "=1.2.0"
    }
    


    
    kubernetes = {
      source = "hashicorp/kubernetes"
          
    }
    
  

    docker = {
      source  = "kreuzwerker/docker"
      version = ">= 2.16.0"
    }


    

    azuread = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azuread"
     // version = "= 2.28.1"
     version = "2.30"
    }


    random = {
      source  = "hashicorp/random"
      version = "=3.1.2"
   // version = "3.0"
    }

  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Check out constraints and limitations: [Integrate your app with an Azure virtual network - Azure App Service | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-vnet-integration#limitations)

**Note :**

> If your app is in an App Service Environment, it's already integrated
> with a virtual network and doesn't require you to configure virtual
> network integration feature to reach resources in the same virtual
> network.
>
> App and the Virtual network should be in the same region.

Comment: I also tried to deploy and it successfully deploys but does not show webpage when I browse... Why? On Azure portal I see no deployment logs...